# How to implement in Dart a bi-directional encryption algorithm that still generates an output if a wrong password is used?

Tags: flutter, algorithm, dart, encryption

In my Flutter app, I want to encrypt and decrypt a String using a bi-directional encryption algorithm.

Let's say I want to encrypt `my secret content` with a given password, for example: `mypassword`. I can encrypt it with pretty much any encryption algorithm.

But I when it comes to decryption, I want that algorithm to behave like the following:

- if I use the right password (`mypassword`), I get `my secret content` back, in my example
- but if I use a wrong password, I want to get another result, that is generated by the algorithm using the encrypted content and the wrong password

So here is an example of what I tried so far, using the [crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) and [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) packages:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as e;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


void test()
{
  const secretContent = "my secret content";
  const password = "mypassword";
  final iv = List.generate(16, (index) => 0);

  final passwordSha = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(password));

  final encrypter = e.Encrypter(e.AES(e.Key(Uint8List.fromList(passwordSha.bytes)), mode: e.AESMode.ctr));
  final encryptedResult = encrypter.encryptBytes(
      secretContent.codeUnits,
      iv: e.IV(Uint8List.fromList(iv)));
  final encryptedText = encryptedResult.base64;

  print("encryptedText: $encryptedText");

  final passwordSha2 = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(password));
  // final passwordSha2 = sha256.convert(utf8.encode("my other password")); // generates an error
  final encrypter2 = e.Encrypter(e.AES(e.Key(Uint8List.fromList(passwordSha2.bytes)), mode: e.AESMode.ctr));
  final decryptedText = encrypter2.decrypt64(encryptedText, iv: e.IV(Uint8List.fromList(iv)));

  print("decryptedText: ${decryptedText}");
}
```

It works fine, as long as I use the same password for encryption and decryption. But if I use another password for decryption, I got an error, while I expect another generated text.

Here is the error: `Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block`

**One important note here:** I could of course find an easy workaround by surrounding my code with a `try catch` block, and generate another String in the `catch` block. But that is not what I'm looking for.

In fact, a hacker could have access to the encrypted content as well as the complete algorithm. He could then remove the `try catch` block and test multiple passwords until he finds the right one.

This is why I'm looking for a bi-directional encryption algorithm that I could implement in Dart, that could generate another content if a wrong password is used. Apparently, I'm looking for a format-preserving encryption algorithm, preferably a strong one like AES, or equivalent.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The exception is not caused by the decryption *itself*, but by the padding. An incorrect decryption (due to a corrupted ciphertext, a wrong key/password, etc.) results in a generally meaningless byte sequence whose padding is not compatible with the specified padding (PKCS#7, the default). This results in the error message *Invalid or corrupted pad block*.

Comment: Note that padding is actually only required for block cipher modes, but not for stream cipher modes. Since you are using a stream cipher mode (namely CTR) you can disable padding: `..., mode: e.AESMode.ctr, padding: null)...` (many libraries do this implicitly for stream cipher modes, not so the *encrypt* package). With this change there are no padding errors anymore and if the key (or password) is wrong a meaningless byte sequence is generated.

Comment: Note that the byte sequence produced by an incorrect decryption is generally not UTF-8 decodable, and that for CTR (and CTR-based modes), reuse of key/IV pairs is a serious vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very interesting explanations! I'm going to try that out tonight, and I may have more questions afterwards.